# Conversion between classes with the same structure under different namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, type-conversion

Say I have a class `A` under namespace `AAA` with a definition like this:

```c++
namespace AAA {
    class A
    {
        int x;
        std::vector<double> y;
        A* ptr;
    };
}
```

And I have another class `B` with the same structure as follow but it is under a different namespace `BBB`,

```c++
namespace BBB {
    class B
    {
        int x;
        std::vector<double> y;
        B* ptr;
    };
}
```

I know the correct way to do this is to have only one definition in the first place but now let's assume we can't change that fact that there is an `AAA::A` class and a `BBB::B` class. Is there a way I can convert an `A` object to a `B` object?

Comment: You can use a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Comment: Converting `AAA::A::y` to `BBB::B::y` and `AAA::A::x` to `BBB::B::x` should  not be a big deal....but how would you like to convert `AAA::A::ptr` to `BBB::B::ptr`....there will be no automatic way to do that...

Comment: _@dhu_ Do you need it one way, or bidirectional convertible? In first case simply follow @0x499602D2's advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no safe conversion whatsoever. The best is a static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(B), "Different Size") followed by a brave reinterpret_cast.